Reset of SwipeToDismissBoxState not working
I build a swipetodismiss box for a lazy column, containing a confirmation dialog.
This is to make sure, we're not accidentially deleting an item from a list, so the user needs to confirm.
The happy case is working (user swipes/user confirms), but when I press cancel I am resetting the state (using SwipeToDismissBoxState.reset()).
Everything seems reset (even the item is animating back) except for the fact that I cannot swipe the item again.
When the item is moved out of sight (due to scrolling e.g.) and reenters the screen it doesn't seem reset at all.
I am resetting the SwipeToDismissBoxState.reset(), I don't know what I am doing wrong...
Compose-Multiplatform-Version: 1.6.11
Here the snippet, feel free to re-use it, once it's working!

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun <T> SwipeToDismissContainer(
    item: T,
    itemName: String,
    animationTime: Int = 300,
    confirmationDialog: Boolean = true,
    onDismiss: (T) -> Unit,
    content: @Composable (T) -> Unit
) {
    var potentialDelete by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var deleteItem by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var resetItem by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val state = rememberSwipeToDismissBoxState(
        confirmValueChange = { dismissValue ->
            when (dismissValue) {
                SwipeToDismissBoxValue.EndToStart,
                SwipeToDismissBoxValue.StartToEnd -> {
                    if (confirmationDialog) {
                        potentialDelete = true
                        true
                    } else {
                        potentialDelete = false
                        deleteItem = true
                        true
                    }
                }

                else -> false
            }
        }
    )

    LaunchedEffect(resetItem) {
        if (resetItem) {
            state.reset()
            resetItem = false
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(deleteItem) {
        if (deleteItem) {
            delay(animationTime.toLong())
            onDismiss(item)
        }
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = !deleteItem,
        exit = shrinkVertically(
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = animationTime),
            shrinkTowards = Alignment.Top
        ) + fadeOut()
    ) {
        SwipeToDismissBox(
            state = state,
            backgroundContent = {
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.errorContainer)
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier.minimumInteractiveComponentSize(),
                        imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Delete, contentDescription = null
                    )
                }
            },
            content = {
                content(item)
            }
        )
    }

    if (confirmationDialog && potentialDelete) {
        SwipeDismissConfirmationDialog(
            itemName = itemName,
            onCancel = {
                potentialDelete = false
                resetItem = true
            }
        ) {
            potentialDelete = false
            deleteItem = true
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun SwipeDismissConfirmationDialog(
    itemName: String,
    onCancel: () -> Unit,
    onConfirm: () -> Unit,
) {
    AlertDialog(
        icon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Delete, contentDescription = null) },
        title = { Text(text = stringResource(Res.string.item_deletion_dialog_title)) },
        text = {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(
                    Res.string.item_deletion_dialog_dialog_description,
                    itemName
                )
            )
        },
        onDismissRequest = {
            onCancel()
        },
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    onConfirm()
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = stringResource(Res.string.item_deletion_dialog_dialog_confirm))
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    onCancel()
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = stringResource(Res.string.item_deletion_dialog_dialog_cancel))
            }
        }
    )
}



I think the problem is in the Material 3 library itself. I've downgraded Compose BOM 2024.06.00 (M3 v1.2.1) to 2023.10.01 (M3 v1.1.2) and the SwipeToDismiss behavior became correct without any changes in the code

From what I can tell, this is either intended behavior or a bug in the M3 library. Not ideal, but here's a decent work around that I'm using. I haven't tested it on Multiplat, but it works for Android native.
The basic idea is to never confirm the value change, then maintain swiped states as if you had confirmed the change. I added a preview for those who may want to play around with the code for their own needs.
@Composable
fun <T> SwipeToDismissContainer(
    item: T,
    itemName: String,
    animationTime: Int = 300,
    confirmationDialog: Boolean = true,
    onDismiss: (T, onError: () -> Unit) -> Unit,
    content: @Composable (T) -> Unit
) {
    var potentialDelete by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var deleteItem by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var stateToMaintain by remember { mutableStateOf<SwipeToDismissBoxValue?>(null) }

    val state = rememberSwipeToDismissBoxState(
        confirmValueChange = { dismissValue ->
            when (dismissValue) {
                SwipeToDismissBoxValue.EndToStart,
                SwipeToDismissBoxValue.StartToEnd -> {
                    if (confirmationDialog) {
                        potentialDelete = true
                    } else {
                        potentialDelete = false
                        deleteItem = true
                    }
                    stateToMaintain = dismissValue
                }
                else -> {}
            }
            false //Immediately resets the state so we can swipe it again if confirmation is canceled or if deletion fails
        }
    )

    //Maintains the row's swiped state while it waits for confirmation and for AnimatedVisibility to hide the item
    LaunchedEffect(stateToMaintain) {
        stateToMaintain?.let {
            state.snapTo(it)
            stateToMaintain = null
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(deleteItem) {
        if (deleteItem) {
            delay(animationTime.toLong())
            onDismiss(item) {
                deleteItem = false
            }
        } else {
            //In our app, the onDismiss function also takes in an onError: () -> Unit,
            //which allows us to bring the item back if deletion fails
            state.reset()
        }
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = !deleteItem,
        exit = shrinkVertically(
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = animationTime),
            shrinkTowards = Alignment.Top
        ) + fadeOut()
    ) {
        SwipeToDismissBox(
            state = state,
            backgroundContent = {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.errorContainer)
                )
            },
            content = {
                content(item)
            }
        )
    }

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    if (confirmationDialog && potentialDelete) {
        SwipeDismissConfirmationDialog(
            itemName = itemName,
            onCancel = {
                potentialDelete = false
                scope.launch { state.reset() } //reset() seems to only reset the visual state, not the full state object
            }
        ) {
            potentialDelete = false
            deleteItem = true
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun SwipeDismissConfirmationDialog(
    itemName: String,
    onCancel: () -> Unit,
    onConfirm: () -> Unit,
) {
    AlertDialog(
        title = { Text(text = "Delete Confirmation") },
        text = { Text("Delete $itemName?") },
        onDismissRequest = onCancel,
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(onClick = onConfirm) {
                Text(text = "Delete")
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(onClick = onCancel) {
                Text(text = "Cancel")
            }
        }
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
private fun Test() {
    val list = (1..100).toList()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Column {
        list.forEach {
            SwipeToDismissContainer(
                it,
                it.toString(),
                onDismiss = { _, onError ->
                    scope.launch {
                        delay(1000)
                        onError()
                    }
                }
            ) { item ->
                Text(
                    text = item.toString(),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


This indeed,  is working on compose multiplatform as well. Thank you!

This is my solution on native Android. I tried to make it as simple as possible. I used a isDeleting mutableState to hide the item while the deletion process is confirmed or not. If the process is not confirmed by the user, the item is restored (by setting isDeleting to false), otherwise the item is removed from the list.
First, the field isDeleting has to be added to the Item data class
data class Item(
    var id: String? = null,
    ...
    var isDeleting: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false)
)

And this is the code:
LazyColumn(
    state = rememberLazyListState()
          ) {
            items(items = itemList, key = { it.id }) { item ->
                val dismissState = rememberSwipeToDismissBoxState(
                    confirmValueChange = { dismissValue ->
                        if (dismissValue == SwipeToDismissBoxValue.EndToStart) {
                            onSwipeToDeleteRequest(item.id)  //the method triggers the dialog to ask the user to confirm the item deletion
                            item.isDeleting.value = true  //to hide the item, while the user confirms or not the deletion process
                        }
                        false  //always false. If isDeleting is true, the user sees the red Box below 
                    })
                SwipeToDismissBox(
                    state = dismissState,
                    enableDismissFromStartToEnd = false,
                    enableDismissFromEndToStart = true,
                    backgroundContent  = {
                        Box(
                            Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .background(Color.Red)
                                .padding(horizontal = 20.dp),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
                           ) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Default.Delete,
                                contentDescription = "Delete Icon",
                                tint = Color.White)
                        }
                    }) {
                        Item(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .alpha(if (item.isDeleting.value == true) 0f else 1f)  //after the swipe, the item is not visible. The user sees the red Box below
                                .background(color = Color.White),
                            item = item)
                        }
            }
}

The method onSwipeToDeleteRequest triggers the dialog to ask the user for the delete confirmation.
If the user confirms, the item has to be removed from the itemList, and the LazyColumn will be updated.
If the user aborts the process, then you can set 
item.isDeleting.value = false

